# Email Message configuration for forgot password

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla's default login module. In forgot module section, I have added one more column called username. Now how shall I send this username along with the token id in the mail?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the following folder:

```
root/components/com_user/models/reset.php
```

---

***Joomla 2.5***

Lines 383 to 388, change this:

```
$body = JText::sprintf(
    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_PASSWORD_RESET_BODY',
    $data['sitename'],
    $data['token'],
    $data['link_text']
);
```

to this:

```
$body = JText::sprintf(
    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_PASSWORD_RESET_BODY',
    $data['fromname'], //added data type to get the username
    $data['sitename'],
    $data['token'],
    $data['link_text']
);
```

---

***Joomla 1.5***

On line 256, change this:

```
$body = JText::sprintf('PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_TEXT', $sitename, $token, $url);
```

to this:

```
$body = JText::sprintf('PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_TEXT', $sitename, $fromname, $token, $url);
```

Comment: But for this particular file, I have not such line. For this I have only 267 lines.

Comment: oh, are you using Joomla 1.5?

Comment: @user1799678 - I have updated my answer for Joomla 1.5 aswell

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect;

```
$data['fromname'], //added data type to get the username
```

This should read ;

```
$data['**username**'], //added data type to get the username
```

Also dont forget you will also need to modify the language string for this email to include and extra `%s.`

So in you email it will now read;

```
%$ = username
%$ = sitename
%$ = verification code
%$ = site link
```